# Multiple answer survey: building a regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, survey

I have survey data with respondents choosing up to three policy objectives to be pursued in their city district. Respondents belong to various age groups (18-24, 25-35 etc.) and live in one of the 27 city districts.

**I want to study the impact of age and city district, as well as the joint impact of both variables on the policy objectives chosen**. Obviously, some of the objectives are more probable to be picked jointly since they have similar background (like building sports infrastructure and organising sports events).

I'm doing my statistical computing in R and I came across this thread, being a perfect match to my problem: [multiple choice data simple logistic regression or multinomial logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105480/multiple-choice-data-simple-logistic-regression-or-multinomial-logistic-regressi).

Still no chance of doing it in R? I know a logistic regression run separately for each objective as dependent variable won't do the trick. Maybe there is a second-best solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two main options to analyse your choice data:

1/ **Multivariate multinomial logit modelling** - Basically you would estimate 3 models (1 for each choice of policy objective) but would also allow the error terms to be correlated across the 3 models (At the very least to account for the "panel" nature of your data [i.e., multiple observations per respondent]).

2/ What was exactly the choice question given to the participants? For instance, if you ask them to pick their top three objectives in a given list, then you could eventually use a **rank-ordered logit model** (You would jointly estimate the probability of being ranked 1st, 2nd, etc.).

Perhaps one practical way of tackling issue would be to treat the data as if they came from 3 separate choice questions - For each respondent you would then have 3 observations (each one corresponding to the choice of one particular policy objective among X available) and you could use a **mixed effects model to analyse your data** - Regarding the predictors, I would include a constant term for each policy objective (Don't forget to specify a reference objective) and then interaction effects between these objective-specific constants and the personal characteristics of the respondents - I think this model is sometimes referred as "McFadden MNL model" in the literature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question asked was: Let us assume that you could freely decide what the money from city budget could be spent on in your city district. Which from the possibilities listed below would you choose? Pick no more than 3 objectives.

Comment: Do you know the order in which objectives/options have been selected? (Maybe it makes sense to assume that 1st selected objective also corresponds to the most important one ...) - It seems to me that you should use a MNL (and then mixed effect logit) model treating your data as if coming from 3 separate choice questions.

Comment: No, the answers weren't ranked in any way. This was an online survey and the respondents could put a check mark beside any of the option(s). That is, they could choose from 1 to 3 policy objectives.